# Finding the basis for vectors perpendicular to a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

Let $W$ be the intersection of the two planes $\pi_{1}$ and $\pi_{2}$ defined by:

\begin{align} \pi_{1} &=\{(x,y,z) \mid x−y−z=0\} \\
\pi_{2}&=\{(x,y,z)∣x+2y+z=0\}. \end{align}

Find a basis for $W^\perp$.

Photo can be found below: 
[image: Exercise]

Please help. Thank you!

Comment: First off: can you find a single (non-zero) vector in $W^\perp$? That is usually a good place to start a basis.

Comment: You know that x- y- z= 0 so that for any vector in W x= y+ z.

Comment: You know that x- y- z= (x, y, z).(1, -1, -1)= 0 so that (1, -1, -1) is in the space. You also know that x+ 2y+ z= (x, y, z).(1, 2, 1)= 0 so that (1, 2, 1) is in the space.  Further, clearly W is a one dimensional space so it orthogonal complement is a two dimensional space.  Hmm, looks like we are done!

Comment: @user247327 You should make that an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all compute the solutions of the system

$x-y-z=0$

$x+2y+z=0.$

Show that these are given by $t(1,-2,3)$ with real $t$.

Then you get $W=\{t(1,-2,3): t \in \mathbb R\}.$

Now look for two linearly independent vectors $(a,b,c), (u,v,v)$ such that $(a,b,c) \perp (1,-2,3)$ and $(u,v,w) \perp (1,-2,3)$.

Then $\{(a,b,c), (u,v,v)\}$  is a basis of $W^{\perp}.$

Comment: Whille you are correct, and this method uses a more general framework (and as an example of what do do if one is stuck and don't know what to do, it works very well), in this specific instance you are making it _much_ more difficult than it needs to be.